# HTML table file in atlas

Tags: qgis, table, html, atlas

I have I field "MEMORIAL" in one of my vector layers with the source of a html file. The file is a table that I would like to appear in my atlas through HTML frame. How can I do that?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use the URL (not the Source) and put as data-defined settings your MEMORIAL field.

[image]

NB : You may have to prepend like in the picture with the `file:///`. You can do that either by using an expression or either by updating your MEMORIAL field.

NB2 : I supposed this MEMORIAL is a field of the coverage layer.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work. I changed it to URL and put the MEMORIAL field as data-defined, also changed the field to look like this (file:///C:/Users/felip/Desktop/15/sintetico.html). If I just set URL whithout the data-defined the table works like a charm, but I needed it to work in the atlas context, so it could bring the table that corresponds to each feature.  - Yes, the field belongs to the coverage layer of the atlas.

Comment: Please consider to report this bug with a sample exemple. Data-defined setting does not seem to work properly. This functionnality works great on qgis 2, I use it every day on an old project. I have not tested on qgis 3 until now and indeed,  it does not work.

Comment: I just report the issue : https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/41590